# Constructing PDA to accept language $\{a^ib^j \mid 0 \leq j \leq 2i\}$

Tags: pushdown-automata

How can I construct a PDA which accepts the language 
$\{a^ib^j \mid 0 \leq j \leq 2i\}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also, the construction should not be too hard if you are familiar with the PDA for $\{ a^k b^k \mid k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the PDA is easy:

> Read the input string. if read $b$ and the stack is empty, reject the string. If see $a$, push two $a$ to the stack. If read $b$, pop a value from the stack. Finally, if read the end of the string, it will be accepted.